# There's a bunch of TCP connections on my PC to '9gag'

Tags: tcp, windows-7

My computer has a bunch of TCP connections to the website 9gag. I used to visit that website a lot a while back but I have not used it in a long time. What's more, I blocked that website from my own computer so I wouldn't waste time on it.

However, even now I have a bunch of TCP connections established and their PID is the same as my antivirus (karasperksy) - wtf?

How many TCP connections is my computer supposed to have when I have no relevant applications running?

EDIT: Running Windows

Comment: Which OS you are running ?

Comment: Windows; edited the original post but if you look at the tag it says windows-7

Comment: How exactly did you "block" the website?

Comment: (@Philipp) In particular, did you set your hosts file, or perhaps your own DNS server or proxy, to resolve 9gag(.whatever) to the 'localhost' address 127.0.0.1 or ::1? If so then all localhost connections may now display as '9gag'. I don't know Kaspersky in particular, but many things containing more than one process use localhost sockets to communicate among them.